# Paypal Integration with website

Tags: paypal, laravel

I am working on a event-based website that requires PayPal payment. I checked the documentation as well as the questions and answers on Stackoverflow. However, I am still don't know what is the best way to accomplish this. The following are the steps that I have to do:

1. An audience registers for an event. He provides all the personal information and choose the sessions that he will attend.
2. The system saves his information into a database and redirects him to the PayPal website so that he can pay by using credit card or PayPal account.
3. After the payment is verified by Paypal, call back to the website so that I can save the payment status in the database and process further steps.

If you have done something similar, please share it with me. Thank you in advance

PS: I am using PHP Laravel Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Omnipay to do via Paypal: https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay

Your steps 2 and 3 are covered, for PayPal and many other payment gatways.

But if you are on US or UK, you should think about using Stripe as payment gateway. It's what Laracasts (by Jeffrey Way) and Userscape (Taylor's company) is using. It's very easy.

Stripe documentation is awsome and there are some stuff written about this, screencasts, like this one: http://www.screenr.com/d3v8 (for Laravel 3, but you'll get the idea) and Composer packages, like those:

http://packalyst.com/packages/package/mosey/stripe

https://github.com/Abodeo/laravel-stripe

Good luck!